# Minimum of four exponential variables

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, exponential-function, actuarial-science

Four accidents occur independently, with each accident following an exponential distribution with a mean of 22.5. What is the expected value of the minimum of the four accidents?

Attempt:

$min(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = n * f(x)* (1-F(x))^{n-1}=4(\frac{1}{22.5}exp(-x/22.5))(exp(-3x/22.5))$

Expectation =$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4x}{22.5}*exp(-x/5.625)dx = 5.625$

However, I believe this is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $m_4\sim exp(\frac 4 {22.5})$ so your computation is correct.

Comment: Strange. I didn't see this option on an exam I previously took. Maybe I'm not remembering the question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, let $X_1,\dotsc, X_n$ be iid eponential distribution with mean $1/\lambda$. Then the distribution of the minimum $M$ is
$$P(M\leq m) = 1-P(M>m) = 1-(e^{-\lambda m})^{n} = 1-e^{-\lambda nm}.$$
Notice that this shows that $M$ follows an exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda n}$. In our case, $\lambda = 1/22.5, n =4$, and so
$$E[M] = \frac{1}{4/22.5} = 5.625.$$
So, our answers agree.

Similarly, if the mean is $90$, then 
$$E[M] = \frac{1}{4/90} = 22.5$$

Comment: Thanks. I believe the initial question stated that the accidents were a mean of 90, which would result in 22.5 using the same process.

Comment: @statsguyz I updated my answer for completeness. Thanks. Good luck.